# codenameone Preferences throwing "Failed to save token" Error

Tags: ios, codenameone, apple-developer

I try to create new apple certificates and it says "Failed to save Token" Error. I have login to itunesconnect.apple.com and successfully accepted the agreement before trying this.Please advise when this error occurs.

There used to be space in the project name and did worked before without any issue and deployed application in app store. Now my certificate got expired. when I tried to regenerate the certificate using the codenameone certificate wizard, it popped error saying path contains space. So I went and deleted the space in the project name and corrected Build.xml and codenameone_settings.properties without space manually. When I tried to connect itunesconnect through codenameone wizard it failed with error "Failed to save token". I have updated AppID in apple itunes connect without space as well to match it. Please advise

[image]

Comment: Have you fixed this? I am having the exact same problem now and its confusing...

Comment: No. I'm still facing the issue.

Comment: Are you sure this is still happening? Did you retry? We made a fix a couple of hours ago and it should be working by now. Make sure you restart Codename One Settings just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The certificate wizard should work now. We had some downtime as I explained here: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/native-logging-certificate-wizard.html

Comment: I have verified now Shai. Earlier Settings might not have refreshed or something  so error was still showing. Now it is fixed. Thank You.